# Looking for alternative to adding an <img> tag inside of a <h> header tag

Tags: html, css, image, header

I see a lot of posts on adding the ***"img"*** tag inside of a ***"header"*** tag and from what I see it's bad practice even though it does what intended for me. I would like to know an alternate way to properly format the way I want.

I have an image icon that I am trying to place left of the ***"h4"*** tag on the same line.  The only way I could figure out on doing this is as follows:

```html
<div class="col-md-4 service-header-bar">
  <h4 class="service-heading"><img src="img/icons/wheel-icon.png" class="icon-size" alt="Furnace Servicing">Furnace Servicing</h4>
  <p class="text-muted service-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.</p>
</div>
```

```css
.page-section .service-header-bar .icon-size {
  margin-right: 20px;
  max-width: 50px;
}
.page-section h2.section-heading {
  font-size: 45px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-family: 'Gotham';
  font-weight: 700;
}
.page-section p.service-paragraph {
  margin-left: 71px;
  margin-right: 35px;
}
.service-heading {
  margin: 15px 0;
  text-transform: none;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of what my code produces, although I would like the same result without using an img tag inside of a h tag.

https://gyazo.com/f139612f2902d5c0152f2eb33026af2c

Thanks in advance,

Nick

Comment: Try `float: left`

Comment: Or use `display: grid;`

Comment: May I know why you want to place the img tag inside the header?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using an img tag you can use a background image for the heading instead. And then extend the class for different images. Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/su3zymj1/).

Markup:

```
<h1 class="heading-icon">Heading</h1>
<h1 class="heading-icon heading-icon-blue">Heading</h1>
```

CSS:

```
.heading-icon {
  padding-left: 50px;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/25x25") left center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.heading-icon-blue {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/25x25/1382d2") left center no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the feed back and help, adding "float: left" in:

```css
.page-section .service-header-bar .icon-size {
  float: left;   
  margin-right: 20px;
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

did exactly what I wanted.

Nick